# Importing variables and functions from another file presenting an error

Tags: python, import

I'm currently in the process of coding a game using Pygame with a group of friends, but I'm finding some trouble when attempting to import between files. I've tried two things, the first is:

```
from Rooms import *
Rooms.Room1Setup(1)
```

which gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'Rooms' is not defined
```

The second is:

```
from Rooms import *
Room1Setup(1)
```

which gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'Room1Setup' is not defined
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The first one won't work because you import everything from Rooms,

If indeed *Room1Setup(1)* exists,

```
import Rooms
Rooms.Room1Setup(1)
```

should work instead.

You can see what Rooms conatins using the dir function

```
import Rooms
print(dir(Rooms))
```

Comment: This returns: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Room1Setup'. I can confirm that Room1Setup does exist, so I've no clue what's happening.

Comment: Are you sure there is a Room1Setup class in Rooms?

Comment: It's a function, actually; sorry for not making that clear. But yes, I am.

Comment: Did you write the function? do you have a link to the source?

Comment: I did, yes. But I don't have a link.

Comment: If we cant see the code we don't really know what's going on, please edit your answer so we can further help you.